# Java - set all object variables to null

Tags: java

I am making a library program, and implementing a `Book` class. This class obviously has tons of details regarding its title, author, if it's check out, etc. I am not requiring the user to input all the details of the book when the book is created, so I was wondering what the best way to cycle through all of an objects class variables in the constructor and set them to `null` for the time being.

I was thinking that there is some way to call a list of a classes variables, and then place them into a for loop and set each individual one to null?

Comment: Look for: java reflection.

Comment: all uninitialized classes at runtime are set to the default value(null for classes, 0 for integer, "" for String,false for boolean and so on

Comment: Reflection would be unnecessary overhead.  Just declare each of them null in the constructor.

Comment: http://dzone.com/snippets/get-all-classes-within-package

Answer (score 3):

All class memeber variables are initialized to their default values automatically i.e. null for objects, 0 for integers etc. So you don't have to explicitly set them to null.